# Json extraction using postgres

Tags: php, json, postgresql, json-extract

I have a json

```json
{
  "timer": {
    "19272": {
      "asset_id": 9354,
      "original_total_time": 5,
      "original_warning_time": null
    }
  },
  "SEBKeys": [],
  "scoreMappings": []
}
```

I need to extract 'original_total_time' value from this json using Postgres.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you're using PHP, you can use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Is there any way that i can get in query itself?

Comment: whether your JSON structure is fix or dynamic

Comment: I got the solution  (SELECT *
, requests.request -> 'notes' -> json_object_keys((requests.request ->> 'notes')::json) ->> 'message' AS message
FROM requests)

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON structure is fixed then you can use following query

```
select json_->'timer'->'19272'->>'original_total_time' from test
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=972857cd0bfab077e0ba9aa9a388b60d)